# How to view the list of all exceptions thrown by a custom class member in C#?

Tags: c#

Visual Studio allows you us view the list of all exceptions thrown by a base class
library member simply by hovering your mouse cursor over the member name in the code window. Is there any way to find it out for the custom class member?

thanks

Comment: Maybe creating custom debug visualizer will help, have you tried it?

Comment: @PawełPoręba: No; that's not what he's talking about.

Comment: You can get strong hints of well-known exceptions that could be caught using the Exceptional plugin for the ReSharper extension for Visual Studio. (You'll probably prefer to tune down the severity to the lowest level.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing the `<exception>` elements of the member's XML doc comments.

To see this for your own code, simply write it in your own doc comments.

There is nothing automatic about this feature.

Code example:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a method that does sometihng
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
/// <exception cref="MyCustomException">This exception can be throw because who knows</exception>
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
 }
```

Comment: As added information, you do this by adding the <exception> element to the XML doc of the method

Comment: Can you please re-phrase your answer?

Comment: @DandC I added a code example